# Thread vs process performance

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ipc

In my application I faced problem of slow startup - I load 11 pages in ViewPager, and it takes abt 11 seconds on old single-core Android device.

Ok, I tried to load 6 of 11 pages in separate threads in hope to make startup faster. It helps on multi-core phones, but on single-core it does not help (not faster) - actually because all the threads (as expected) cannot run truly in parallel, so multithreading is useless for performance in this case, if you have only one core :(

So the last hope is - to split loading in two processes (eg. create a Service in separate process), and the main question is here: is it worth to do? Will two processes on single-core device do the same work faster than multiple threads in a single process?

Comment: A single processor can execute 1 instruction at a time. Whether you call the thing they belong to thread or process does not matter. 1000 instructions take 1000 cycles to complete.

Comment: Ok, what about RAM impact? Separated threads have separate memory amounts. If we run several threads in one process, can Android limit threads performance because of per-process memory limit, even if the limit has not been reached yet? If yes, than I suppose two processes can be faster, than two threads... It is just an assumption.